# How to Round 46.565 to 46.57 in Java? (no ceiling)

Tags: java, math, rounding

I've been using Math.round and everything seemed fine until I noticed that any number that ended in "5" wasn't rounded.

```
double roundtotal = Math.round(total * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

Which rounds to 2 decimal places, but doesn't round 46.565 to 46.57 for example

Can anyone help?

Comment: Works for me: http://pastie.org/8232041

Comment: It does here http://ideone.com/20A6rb prints `46.565 rounded to 2 places is 46.57`

Comment: `System.out.println(Math.round(46.565 * 100.0) / 100.0);` Output: `46.57`.

Comment: ah solved it, accidentally made total a float, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: This is *dangerous*!  Remember that your machine uses binary floats, so `46.565` *is not* exactly 46 and 565 thousandths.  It's an approximation which is either a tiny amount larger than the exact decimal value, or a tiny amount smaller.  And if it's a tiny amount larger, it should round up, while if it's a tiny amount smaller, it should round down.  You shouldn't have any expectations about which direction a binary approximation to a decimal halfway case will round.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12684082/207421) for why that doesn't and cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
double roundtotal = ((int)((total*100.0)+0.5)) / 100.0;
```